# read an array dynamically using getElementById

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read values from a form dynamically created by user and insert them in an 2 dimensional array. The ID of any field is created dynamically and it has the value 11, 12, 13 etc, depending on the rows and cols of the table.
I try to read it using getElementByID but it seems to not work. The function is as follows:

```
            function readMatrix () {
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
            A[i][j]=parseFloat(getElementById(ij).value, 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are leaking globals `i` and `j`. Use `var` to avoid this!! And `parseFloat` does not have a 2nd `base` argument. Unless you are using HTML5 you also cannot have an ID starting with a number.

Comment: my bad to the below comments. it works perfectly, i made a mistake some place else in the script

Comment: You firebug (if you are not using it) Highly recommended. getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's `document.getElementById(...)` - that part is important, otherwise it can't find the `getElementById` function.

Next, you're having it look for a variable called `ij`, which is not what you want. You want the two numbers concatenated, so that can either be `i*10+j` or `""+i+j`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: It does work, you're just doing something else wrong. Please show your updated code.

Comment: yes you are right I was doing something else wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with `getElementById` call and argument. Try this:

```
function readMatrix() {
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            var id = "" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
            A[i][j] = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);
        }
    }
}​
```

Pay attention you have IDs starting from `11` but not `00`, so `(i + 1) + (j + 1)` part is added.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VnvM2/

Comment: the +1 part seems legit, however the function is not working in this form, nor with "A"+(i+1)+(j+1)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, elements id is concantenation of `i` and `j` , rather than addition.

So, it should work,

```
   function readMatrix () {
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
            A[i][j]=parseFloat(document.getElementById(i + '' + j).value, 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to get value of which html element ?

Comment: Mark question as answer that helps you :)